# org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

My test checks to see if I can send a message to the mail.
When I click the send button should check the alert.

My code for alert is:

```
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        System.out.println(alert.getText());
        alert.accept();
        Assert.assertTrue(alert.getText().contains("Thanks."));
```

My error is:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 13707
Only local connections are allowed.

org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 76 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '31c43c8', time: '2016-08-02 21:57:56 -0700'
System info: host: 'Gaga', ip: '192.168.1.6', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed), userDataDir=C:\Users\Dragana\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir6652_7181}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=55.0.2883.87, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: b7131fce27b2ef40f1daff3c82188e7c
```

Comment: is it because you accepted the alert first and then tried to get the text !?

Comment: I don't know, this is my first alert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code has to wait for alert. Below is the sample code

```
try {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println(alert.getText());
    alert.accept();
    Assert.assertTrue(alert.getText().contains("Thanks."));
} catch (Exception e) {
    //exception handling
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: still same exception for me even though it has opened alert window

Answer (score 2):

This is a very bad approach to use `try-catch` especially in selenium based test cases and their use should be limited:

**Let's understand the real solution of this problem and why the given solution is incorrect because:**

1. If we try to call  `alert.getText()` after  `alert.accept();` it would obvious that it going to throw error because we have already closed the alert.
2. It is working fine because by using `try-catch`, it will going to handle the exception.
3. The problem is that assertion is never checked here.

**Code: The below code will terminate every time even before checking the assertion.**

```
alert.accept();    
Assert.assertTrue(alert.getText().contains("Thanks."));
```

---

**Corrected Code:** The `alert.accept();` should be call after getting the text.

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    Assert.assertTrue(alert.getText().contains("Thanks."));
    alert.accept();
```

Comment: This really worked for me. Thanks !!